# Convergence of naive iteration for a stateful, iterated tabular game

Tags: game-theory

**Summary:** Consider a stateful, two-player zero-sum game: at each state, two players pick moves simultaneously, and the reward and next state depends on those moves.  We can attempt to solve such a game by guessing the value function (the value of each state in the infinitely repeated game, then computing optimal play at each state (say, using linear programming).  This gives a new estimate of the value, and we can iterate.  When does this converge, assuming no discounting of future value ($\gamma = 1$)?

Let $S$ be a finite set of states, and for each $s \in S$ let $A_s \in \mathbb{R}^{m_s \times n_s}$ be the payoff matrix to the first player and $T_{sij}$ be the next state if the players choose moves $i,j$.  Note that the set of moves (and thus the size of $A_s$) varies based on the state, though this is nonessential.  Given a discount rate $\gamma \in [0,1)$, the value function $V : S \times S \to \mathbb{R}$ is the solution to
\begin{align}
V(s) &= \max_{x \in \Delta^{m_s}} \min_{y \in \Delta^{n_s}} \sum_{ij} \left[A_{ij} + \gamma V(T_{sij}) \right]x_iy_j
\end{align}
Here $\Delta^k = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^k~|~0 \le x, \sum_i x_i = 1\}$ is the set of probability distributions over $k$ options.

I believe a solution always exists and is unique for $\gamma < 1$, and can be found using naive iteration: start with some guess $V_0$ for $V$, and iterate the equation until convergence:
\begin{align}
V_{k+1}(s) &= \max_{x \in \Delta^{m_s}} \min_{y \in \Delta^{n_s}} \sum_{ij} \left[A_{ij} + \gamma V_k(T_{sij}) \right]x_iy_j
\end{align}

However, naive iteration can also converge if $\gamma = 1$.  This requires additional assumptions about the game, in particular that $V$ is finite: there is no state where one player can accrue steady advantage if play continues forever.

**Question:** What are sufficient conditions for naive iteration to converge with $\gamma = 1$?

Intuitively I would guess that convergence holds whenever (1) all states have finite value and (2) optimal play is ergodic, where we need (2) to avoid repeated cycles.  And we can get convergence assuming (1) only if we add a learning rate $\alpha \in (0,1)$:

\begin{align}
V_{k+1}(s) &= (1-\alpha)V_k(s) + \alpha \max_{x \in \Delta^{m_s}} \min_{y \in \Delta^{n_s}} \sum_{ij} \left[A_{ij} + \gamma V_k(T_{sij}) \right]x_iy_j
\end{align}

Note that in the $\gamma = 1$ case the solution is nonunique: we can add a constant to any solution.

The particular case where I noticed this was the rock-paper-scissors variant [from this thread](https://mastodon.social/@irving/112085295593213164).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value iteration operator

$$\Psi(V) = max_{x \in \Delta^{m_s}} \min_{y \in \Delta^{n_s}} \sum_{ij} [A_{ij} + \gamma V(T_{s i j})] x_i y_j$$

is the Shapley operator for the game. When the discount rate $\gamma < 1$ and $n = |S|$ is finite, the Shapley operator is a strict contraction with respect to the $L^\infty$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  When $\gamma =1$ the Shapley operator is a special case of what is sometimes called a topical map in the literature.  A *topical map* is any function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that is order-preserving and additively homogeneous. Here *order-presevering* means with respect to the entrywise partial ordering on $\mathbb{R}^n$: $v \ge w$ when each entry $v_i \ge w_i$, and *additively homogeneous* means that $\Psi(v + c \mathbf{1}) = \Psi(v) + c\mathbf{1}$ for any real constant $c$ when $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector with a one in every entry.  Topical maps are always nonexpansive with respect to the $\infty$-norm, but are not generally strict contractions.

In general, it is a very difficult problem to know when topical maps have fixed points.  There are some relatively well known sufficient conditions for the existence of additive eigenvectors, i.e., $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Psi(v) = v + c\mathbf{1}$ for some real constant $c$. A good reference is the book *Nonlinear Perron-Frobenius Theory* by Lemmens & Nussbaum.

Assuming that a fixed point does exist, you are correct that the relaxed iteration process obtained by iterating the map $(1-\alpha) \operatorname{id} + \alpha \Psi$ with $0 < \alpha < 1$ will always converge to a fixed point.  This is the Krasnoselski-Mann iteration algorithm for nonexpansive maps.  Without the relaxation factor (i.e., when $\alpha = 1$), the iterates may converge to a fixed point or to some periodic orbit, and again it can be hard to tell which will happen in general. One nice sufficient condition to ensure convergence (assuming a fixed point exists), is if $\Psi$ is *type-K order preserving*, that is if $\Psi(V)_s > \Psi(W)_s$ whenever $V \ge W$ and $V_s > W_s$.  This condition was introduced by Jiang in:

*Jiang, J.* Sublinear discrete-time order-preserving dynamical systems. *Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society*, Volume 119, Issue 3, April 1996, pp. 561 - 574.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!  It seems reasonable that it’s hard to know if the unrelaxed iteration convergence, but it’s great to know that fixed point existence is enough when relaxed.

Comment: If convergence is only possible to a fixed point or cycle if $\alpha = 1$, does that mean the length of the cycle is bounded by some function of the number of states?  Otherwise I would expect compactness to say that convergence to a chaotic path is possible too.

Comment: There is an upper bound on the periods of any periodic orbits of any topical map on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which I believe is $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$. The Nonlinear Perron-Frobenious Theory book by Lemmens & Nussbaum has the details in Chapter 4. Because the Shapley operators are nonexpansive, you won't get any chaotic behavior. If the iterates are bounded they always either converge to a fixed point or to a periodic orbit with a finite period.

Answer (score 1):

The class of games you describe is called "stochastic games". There is a rich literature on algorithmic aspects of these games. Look for surveys and papers by Raghavan, Filar, and their co-authors.
Eilon